# Tengo un problema con la enumeración en el programa

Tags: c++

El programa compila pero hay un problema, a la hora de correrlo de que al colocar 1 estado y 2 sucursales te pide que coloque el número de empleados, colocas 2 luego al terminar eso te pide los empleados de la 2 sucursal si colocas 2 de nuevo da 0.

Este es mi código:

```
void CST2()
{
    int ten[8][6],ne,ns,ce,cs,c,ac,s,p,n,may;
    cout<<"coloque el numero de estados: ";
    cin>>ne;
    cout<<"coloque el numero de sucursales: ";
    cin>>ns;
    ce=0;
    c=0;
    s=0;
    while(ce<ne)
    {
        ce=ce+1;
        cs=0;
        while(cs<ns)
        {
            cs=cs+1;
            cout<<"coloque la cantidad de los empleados del" << ce << " estado de las " << cs << " sucursales: ";
            cin>>n;
            ac=0;
            while(c<n)
            {
                c=c+1;
                cout<<"coloque el sueldo de los " << c << " empleados del " << ce << " estado de la " << cs << " sucirsal: ";
                cin>>s;
                ac=c+s;
            }
            p=ac/n;
            ten[ce][cs]=p;
            cout<<"sueldo " << s << " de los " << c << " empleados de la " << cs << " sucursal y del " << ce << " estado ";
     }
 }
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería la pregunta? No me quedó claro... Además, si le pones nombres que signifiquen algo a las variables, tal vez sea más fácil de leer el programa...

Comment: Estas preguntas me parecen la tarea de la escuela =P, Es tarea Alex? Describe que es lo que tiene que realizar tu programa para ayudarte.

Comment: eeehhh si es un programa de la uni xD pero ese error siempre me a ocurrido  pero nunca lo eh podido acomodar

Answer (score 1):

Mueve la inicialización de la variable `c` dentro del segundo bucle `while`.

Ahora mismo le asignas el valor 0 antes de entrar en el primer bucle, por lo que el contador de empleados no se reinicializa de estado a estado (ni de sucursal a sucursal) y eso afectará al número de veces que se ejecuta el tercer bucle (`while(c<n)`).

En ese bucle estás comparando el número de empleados de esa sucursal específica, pero tal y como está el programa ahora, `c` contiene el número total de empleados (en todas las sucursales, en todos los estados).

El código se vería así:

```
void CST2()
{
    int ten[8][6],ne,ns,ce,cs,c,ac,s,p,n,may;
    cout<<"coloque el numero de estados: ";
    cin>>ne;
    cout<<"coloque el numero de sucursales: ";
    cin>>ns;
    ce=0;
    s=0;
    while(ce<ne)
    {
        ce=ce+1;
        cs=0;
        while(cs<ns)
        {
            // mueve la variable aqui
            c=0;
            cs=cs+1;
            cout<<"coloque la cantidad de los empleados del" << ce << " estado de las " << cs << " sucursales: ";
            cin>>n;
            ac=0;
            while(c<n)
            {
                c=c+1;
                cout<<"coloque el sueldo de los " << c << " empleados del " << ce << " estado de la " << cs << " sucirsal: ";
                cin>>s;
                ac=c+s;
            }
            p=ac/n;
            ten[ce][cs]=p;
            cout<<"sueldo " << s << " de los " << c << " empleados de la " << cs << " sucursal y del " << ce << " estado ";
     }
 }
```

Pruébalo y comenta si funciona o si recibes algún fallo.

Comment: ufff muchas gracias amigo de verdad ya con esto puedo seguir con el programa xD

Comment: Recibí dos mensajes, una diciendo que no funcionaba y ahora éste que dice que sí funcionó. ¿Todo bien?

Comment: que en serio? no si todo bien gracias

Answer (score 0):

creo que esta es la sentencia que quieres poner:

```
ac += s;
```

y no

```
ac = c + s;
// ac se queda al final del bucle con el ultimo sueldo + el valor del contador ?!?!?!.
```